# Python vs Java Loop

Tags: java, python, string, for-loop

I am working through some problems on HackerRank, and I thought I would try implementing the same solution in Python that I had already solved correctly in Java. Although my code almost exactly mirrors my previous Python solution, I am getting an out of bounds exception in the `if input_str[i-1] == input_str[i]` line. Is there different behavior in a Python loop that might be causing this discrepancy? The test cases are the same across both.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        solve(input);
    }
    public static void solve(String str) {
        String s = new String(str);
        for (int i=1; i < s.length(); i++) {
           if (s.charAt(i-1) == s.charAt(i)) {
               s = s.substring(0, i-1) + s.substring(i+1, s.length());
               i = 0;
           }
           if (s.length() == 0) {
               System.out.println("Empty String");
               return;
           }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the same problem, but using Python 2.7.

```
input_str = raw_input()
for i in xrange(1, len(input_str)):
    if input_str[i-1] == input_str[i]:
        input_str = input_str[0:i-1] + input_str[i+1:len(input_str)]
        i = 0
    if len(input_str) == 0:
        print "Empty String"
        break

print input_str
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Java loop, `s.length()` is recalculated every iteration. In Python, `len(input_str)` is only calculated once and does not reflect the correct length after you've modified `input_str` in the `if` block.

Similarly, assigning `i = 0` does not work the way you want it to. `i` will take on the next value in the `xrange`, ignoring your attempted reset of its value.

Comment: Is there a Python alternative to mimic the behavior of the Java for loop? Something where I could modify the loop bound dynamically?

Comment: Really the only thing you could do if you want something that looks like that for loop is a python `while` loop. Other ways of solving your problem is by using recursion instead or by changing your algorithm so that it only needs a static for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are wasting a lot of time and system resources by doing it that way. A better solution would be to change the algorithm into one that only iterates `input_str` only once. In which case, you get `O(n)` execution time. My edited code looks thus:

```
input_str = input()
input_strR = input_str[0]
for i in range(1, len(input_str)):
    if input_str[i-1] != input_str[i]:
        input_strR = input_strR + input_str[i]
    if len(input_str) == 0:
        print ("Empty String")
        break

print (input_strR)
```

In this case, a new variable was introduced and all first characters were added while duplicates were dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I would build on funaquarius24 and not even use indexes:

```
input_str = raw_input()
result = input_str[0]
for c in input_str[1:]:
    if c != result[-1]:
        result += c
print(result)
```